# Center to right by parent

Tags: html, css

I'm working at my new intranet page.

Currently I have something like that :

[image]

I want to have :

[image]

Is there any way to center my text to right by it parent (image) ?

That is my code, but it doesn't work :

```
<body style="background-color:#FFCC66">
<br/><a href="/" title="Przejdź do strony głównej">
         <img style="display:block;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto"
              src="/logointra.png" alt="Logo Intranetu" /></a>
<br/>
<span style="display:block; position:relative; text-align:right">
     I wanna be centered to right by my parent - image</span>
```

Comment: The problem is that the `span` is filling the width of the parent block.  The quick fix is to assign the width of the image.

Comment: @MarcAudet can you expand your answer ?

Comment: The answer by Robert Nowak is essentially what I had in mind except with a wrapper, which is probably a bit more robust.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/xrJ2z/5/

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <img src="intranet.jpg">
    <div>i'm placed right</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container {
    width:200px;
    margin:auto auto; /*set div in center*/
    background-color:red;
    text-align:right;
}
img {
    display:block; /*Marc Audet Tip*//*remove unnecessary space between img and text div*/
}
```

P.S.

```
<div> is like <span style="display:block">
```

Comment: You are basically right, see http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/xrJ2z/3/ if you display the image as a block, you get rid of the baseline white space effect. (fix your fiddle and post your html and css).

Comment: Also, I tend to reset the base of jsfiddle to get rid of the version number of the URL, but that is my personal preference.

Comment: Dziękuję za odpowiedź :)

Comment: @MarcAudet Yes you need :) "Dziękuję za odpowiedź" means "Thanks for your answer" :)

Answer (score 2):

If you do not want to add a wrapper element, you need to do the following:

```
<a href="/" title="Przejd? do strony g?ównej">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/400x100" alt="Logo Intranetu" />
</a>
<span>I wanna be centered to right by my parent - image</span>
```

and for the CSS:

```css
body {
    background-color: #FC6;
}
img {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
span {
    display: block;
    width: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: right;
}
```

See demo at http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/xdkGV/

Because an image has an intrinsic width, `margin: 0 auto` centers the image as you expect.

Note that the space to the left and to the right of the image is also clickable.

The `span`, displayed as a block element, needs to be given a width to match the image.
In this case, the `margin: 0 auto` centering works and `text-align: right` forces the text to match the right edge of the image.

Answer (score 1):

This is what you want? **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kFJ95/)**.

Just add a "*container*" element that envolves the `img` and `span` element, and then `float` the inner elements to left.

**HTML**:

```
<div class="container">
<a href="/" title="Przejdź do strony głównej">
    <img src="/logointra.png" alt="Logo Intranetu" />
</a>
<span style="display:block; position:relative; text-align:right">I wanna be centered to right by my parent - image</span>
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
body {
    background-color: #FC6;
    text-align: center;
}
.container {
    display: inline-block;
}

.container > * {
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: No, If I will write that code my text will be centered **not to right**, firstly. Secondary it will be centered into the center of page not image. Please read my question carefully.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your image and span in a `<div>` element and set the css float property of the span to right.

```
<div><a href="/" title="Przejdź do strony głównej">
     <img style="display:block;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto"
          src="/logointra.png" alt="Logo Intranetu" /></a>
<br/>
<span style="display:block; position:relative; text-align:right; float:right;">
 I wanna be centered to right by my parent - image</span></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<body style="background-color:#FFCC66"><br/><div style="margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto"><a href="/" title="Przejdź do strony głównej"><img src="/logointra.png" alt="Logo Intranetu" /></a>
<br/><span style="text-align:right">I wanna be centered to right by my parent - image</span></div>
```